# Silverlight 4 & VisualSVN issue

Tags: silverlight, visualsvn

I recently started using VisualSVN to sync my solutions to my Dropbox folder. But in the Silverlight solution, I get an error when trying to run.

"The Silverlight project you are about to debug uses WCF RIA services. WCF RIA services will fail unless the Silverlight project is hosted in and launched from the same web project that contains the WCF RIA services."

I'm not sure, but I guess the problem lies with the fact that it's in my Dropbox folder, although I'm not really sure, since nothing changed to the solution since I installed VisualSVN.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your startup project is the YourProject.Web